# Laptop turns on automatically after shutdown

Tags: windows, acer

I have a Acer Swift SF314 laptop running Windows 10. For the last few months my laptop has been turning itself on immediately after I shut it down. That is, once I click shutdown from windows and the device powers down, it automatically boots after mere seconds.

I have to press the power button to shut down the machine everytime; this works as expected. But I am worried I might damage the system in the long run.

I tried turning off fast boot and similar readily available solutions, but no luck.

Any idea how I can identify the issue? Can this be a hardware issue? If so, any inputs on how I can identify which piece of the hardware is at fault?

Comment: Can you also test it with booting thru some Live Linux USB key? Does the behavior repeat when you shut it down from another OS like Live Linux? You do not need to install Live Linux, it can run off RAM disk as Live OS without anything getting installed on the storage device like HDD/SSD.

Comment: We have the exact problem with a Desktop computer. Anytime you shut it down, it will reboot on its own. Turns out, although being sold as a complete system, the motherboard and the GPU don't like each other, so the GPU triggers a restart every time we shut down Windows. A possible future BIOS update could solve this, but we're waiting since forever. 
With Laptops, that's rather rare, those come hardly with untested configurations, but you could investigate this route. If you exchanged especially the RAM, you could try switching back to the old RAM, or just test your RAM through Windows.

Comment: Do you have an Ethernet cable plugged into this laptop? Perhaps the net-adapter is waking up the machine.

Comment: @patkim, I will try that.

Comment: @physalis I did change one of my RAM sticks, but that was relatively a long time back. And this is a relatively new issue. So it should not be the cause. But I can still investigate, Do you have any suggestions on how I can test the RAM?

Comment: @mastaxx No, I do not have any ethernet cable plugged in. I think I also tried to disable the option for net-adapter to wake the machine after following some StackExchange thread (don't remember for sure though).

Comment: I don't pretend to know if this is the issue or not. Can a faulty battery be causing it? Is the battery one that can be removed without opening the laptop? I wonder if without battery and only power cable if it behaves the same way.

Comment: @patkim looks the laptop still turns on even if I turn off from the linux system.

Comment: @Mastaxx, good idea. I'll try removing the battery and check. Unfortunately it's not easily removable. But I think I can still try it.

Comment: The only other thing i can think of is a faulty power button.

Comment: @dotdeb You should find all info [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/260813/how-to-test-your-computers-ram-for-problems/). On Windows machines, so many components and possible causes for trouble come together, so it might even be the RAM after such a long time :). But I'm no expert when it comes to that, just an idea I head when I read about your problem. Would it be possible to just change back the RAM, or remove the new bar if you have two installed, for testing?

Comment: @physalis, thanks for the link! Unfortunately I do not have the old RAM stick anymore :(